# What object types are avaliable for export on <hostname>/phonograph2-export/api/?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is it possible to export to anything but Excel? I'm currently using `export-object-set-to-excel` and could not locate where in the docs this is listed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely export and import object sets within Foundry. For external export though, I doubt anything but excel is allowed through this endpoint. Seems like there aren't public facing docs for these internal endpoints, so we're on our own using it I think.

What were you hoping for? If you provide some more details on your use case we might be able to help you find some alternative.

Comment: CSV would be best or an available list of endpoints for future reference. Mainly because we've had some issues using AWS regarding reading and writing to Excel.  I was enquiring if it was available or if I was missing the docs.  In the meantime, we've resolved the AWS dependencies.